# Where are my links?

Tags: casperjs

I am trying to run a basic casperjs script that logs into a website then shows me the links. However my output is not returning anything other then `'Done'`

Here is my code

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start('http://xxxxxx/Login.aspx', function(){
  //Login
  this.fill('form#form1', {
    'username': 'xxxxx',
    'password': 'xxxxx'
    }, true);
});

casper.then(function(){
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(var i = 0; i < links.length; ++i) {
    //These should show something
    this.echo(links[i].innerText;
    this.echo(this.getHTML());
  }
});
casper.run(function(){
  this.echo('done').exit();
  });
```

Like I said, the only thing I get back is "done".

Answer (score 0):

You use getElementsByTagName in the CasperJS context, you can't do that here, you have to pass in the page context by using the evaluate function (see evaluate, thenEvaluate).
If you just want to print the text of a link, use that in your casper.then :

```
this.echo(this.fetchText('a'));
```

And you forgot a bracket too here : this.echo(links[i].innerText;

When you iterate in casperjs, you should use each (IIFE) : http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#each